# For coprime nonzero $c$,$d$, can these quartic homogeneous polynomials in $c,d$ be simultaneously squares of integers?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Are there any nontrivial integer solutions $c,d$ for which $$f(c,d)=|-c^4 - 16 c^3 d + 6 c^2 d^2 + 16 c d^3 - d^4|$$ and $$g(c,d)=|-c^4 + c^3 d + 6 c^2 d^2 - c d^3 - d^4|$$ are simultaneously squares of integers?

By nontrivial, I mean cases where $c,d$ are nonzero and coprime. To avoid any confusion, I explicitly rule out $(c,d) 
= (1,1),(1,-1),(-1,1),(-1,-1)$.

---

My bet is no. Here is Mathematica code checking that all pairs of coprime integers of magnitude less than $1000$ do not solve the equation.

```
CoprimeSet[n_, m_] := 
  Pick[#, CoprimeQ @@@ #] &[Subsets[Range[n], {m}]];
mset = CoprimeSet[1000, 2];
mset2 = Transpose[{1, -1}*Transpose[mset]];
mtemX[c_, d_] := -c^4 - 16 c^3 d + 6 c^2 d^2 + 16 c d^3 - d^4;
mtemY[c_, d_] := - c^4 + c^3 d + 6 c^2 d^2 - c d^3 - d^4;
Total[Boole[Sqrt[Abs[mtemX[#[[1]], #[[2]]]] ] \[Element] Integers]*
    Boole[Sqrt[Abs[mtemY[#[[1]], #[[2]]]]] \[Element] Integers] & /@ 
  mset]
Total[Boole[Sqrt[Abs[mtemX[#[[1]], #[[2]]]] ] \[Element] Integers]*
    Boole[Sqrt[Abs[mtemY[#[[1]], #[[2]]]]] \[Element] Integers] & /@ 
  mset2]
```

---

While these expressions might seem like they come from nowhere, they're actually motivated by a recent [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/453864) that in part is asking whether $x^4 + y^4 = 17 z^4$ has nontrivial positive integer solutions besides $(x,y,z)=(1,2,1)$. If both $f(c,d)$ and $g(c,d)$ can be simultaneously square, one can construct another nontrivial solution to $x^4 + y^4 = 17 z^4$. I suspect there won't be an easy answer to my question above, but if there is, that could help answer that MO question.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, there are no nonzero, coprime choices for $c,d$ for which $f(c,d)$ and $g(c,d)$ are both squares of integers. This follows from the discussion in the question and Flynn and Wetherell's [proof](https://ora.ox.ac.uk/objects/uuid:2f315a79-23b5-4ee7-8a26-fb825316bd9c) that all of the integer solutions to $x^4 + y^4 = 17 z^4$ are trivially related to that of $(x,y,z) = (2,1,1)$.

However, this might not feel entirely satisfactory, so I will leave this question open for answers that more directly tackle the problem.